# Scanner class as function parameter - how to refer to it

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Could anyone tell me how I can refer to a Scanner class as a function parameter? What I mean by that is:
If I have a main function:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{ Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
 int a = nextInt();
 int b = nextInt();
 isPositive(<how do i refer to a and b here>);
}
public static bolean isPositive(Scanner in)
{ <how do I refer to a and b here, to check if (a - b) > 0 )
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

One of the issues you have here is not calling your scanner correctly.

```
 int a = in.nextInt();
 int b = in.nextInt();
```

From here you can pass the values obtained from the scanner into your class isPositive

> public static boolean isPositive(int a, int b) { }

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems in your code. bmarkoe mentioned the incorrect use of the scanner class (it should be `in.nextInt()` not `nextInt()` ).

The `scanner` class isn't actually holding the values of `a` and `b`. Instead, pass `a` and `b` as function parameters (example below). Also, you misspelled `boolean` as `bolean` :)

```
public static boolean isPositive(int first, int second) {
  //some code
}
```

p.s: You can name the function parameters whatever you want (e.g `first` can be called `f`)